# Dreamweaver ASP update record not passing query string

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, dreamweaver

I am trying to update a record in a SQL database using Dreamweaver which work fine on its own, but I want the goto url to show the updated product record.

I have tried to figure this out using some online tutorials but keep coming up with this error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/coding_requests/dashboard.asp, line 33
```

This is my code;

```vb
<%
If (CStr(Request("MM_update")) = "coding_technical_code") Then
  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
    ' execute the update
    Dim MM_editCmd

    Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_conn_PSCRM_Demo_STRING
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DBA.coding_requests SET prodref = ?, lastupdatedby = ?, coding_status = ? WHERE prodref = ?" 
    MM_editCmd.Prepared = true
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 201, 1, 25, Request.Form("prodref")) ' adLongVarChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param2", 201, 1, 3, Request.Form("lastupdatedby")) ' adLongVarChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param3", 201, 1, 6, Request.Form("coding_status")) ' adLongVarChar
    MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param4", 200, 1, 25, Request.Form("MM_recordId")) ' adVarChar
    MM_editCmd.Execute
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

    ' append the query string to the redirect URL
    Dim MM_editRedirectUrl
    MM_editRedirectUrl = "coding.asp?prodref=" & (RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView.Fields.Item("prodref").Value)
    If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
      If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
      Else
        MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
      End If
    End If
    Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
  End If
End If
%>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that the code from `dashboard.asp`, If so can you point to the specific line (line 33) that causes the error?

Comment: Line 33: MM_editRedirectUrl = "coding.asp?prodref=" & (RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView.Fields.Item("prodref").Value)

Comment: I did wonder if that might be the line, in which case it's the fact that `RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView` has not been set. Your referencing it as an object *(I would say a `ADODB.Recordset`)* but can't see anywhere it is instantiated in the code. Usually would have something like `Set RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` and use `RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView.Open()` to execute a query and return a recordset.

Comment: If `Request.Form("prodref")` has the same value as that one, you could use that instead ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ True, if that is the OP's intent. Not sure where `RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView` even comes from if that's the case.

Comment: @Lankymart yes, cannot see any recordset being opened in that bit of code.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Exactly my point in my initial [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476477/dreamweaver-asp-update-record-not-passing-query-string/28477727#comment45277092_28476477).

Comment: @SearchAndResQ your comment In using Request.Form("prodded") worked a treat!

Comment: @JonathanGriffin great. You could accept the answer given by lankymart, which includes reference to that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is simply that line 33 contains an Object Reference *(which is a variable that is created with `Set variablename =`)* but the runtime cannot identify it as an Object Reference that has been created (instantiated).

The line 33 as explained in the comments points to

```
MM_editRedirectUrl = "coding.asp?prodref=" & (RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView.Fields.Item("prodref").Value)
```

The Object Reference on this line is `RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView` but no where in the provided code is the Object Reference `RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView` instantiated using

```
Set RS_Dashboard_Coding_TechnicalView = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

*The above line is an educated guess based on the name of the Object Reference and the methods you are attempting to use (`.Fields.Item()`).*

---

If you are just trying to pass the value of `prodref` from your Form POST to the `MM_editRedirectUrl` variable as [@SearchAndResQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682881/searchandresq) suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476477/dreamweaver-asp-update-record-not-passing-query-string#comment45277395_28476477) just pass the value of `Request.Form("prodref")` which you already have to hand so that line would be;

```
MM_editRedirectUrl = "coding.asp?prodref=" & Request.Form("profref")
```